# Entity Framework code-first : How to fix error with self-reference foreign key in SQL using Annotations

Tags: entity-framework, testing, automated-tests

I have trouble with the database, I use a table `t_CTDaotao sc_HeNganh`. The problem here is that the self-referencing key `t_CTDaotao1` can only refer to `sc_HeNganh1`, and the key `t_CTDaotao2` cannot reference `sc_HeNganh2`, more correctly it only reference 1 key, not multiple keys

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNs2y.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bc6h.png)

Comment: please do not put links to images in your post. Instead, copy-paste the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `[ForeignKey]` attributes on the navigation properties, not the foreign key columns.

Please try this:

```
public int MaHN { get; set; }

public int MaKhoi { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("sc_HeNganh")]
public virtual sc_HeNganh sc_HeNganh { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("sc_Khoilop")]
public virtual sc_Khoilop sc_Khoilop { get; set; }
```